# firebase dynamic links constructed via REST specify social preview info

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Im generating a [dynamic link via REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest)

but I want to include the [social preview info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews)

How to include the values for

> st, sd, si

this is the body of my request

```
{
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
    "domainUriPrefix": "https://wi.page.link",
    "link": "https://wiapp.com.au/faq/123",
    "iosInfo": {
      "iosBundleId": "com.directnance.sr"
    }
    },
    "suffix": {
     "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking some examples and checking [data explorer](https://cloud.aapi.io/openAPI/exploredata/MEUmQHc4NWhldEVPN3J5Nn2lHVI=), here how to construct the body for social preview:

```
{
"dynamicLinkInfo": {
"domainUriPrefix": "https://wi.page.link",
"link": "https://wi.com.au/faq/123",
"iosInfo": {
  "iosBundleId": "com.dirnance.Wr"
},
  "socialMetaTagInfo" :{
  "socialImageLink":"https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/doraemon/images/b/b8/Doraemon_2005.PNG/revision/latest?cb=20151207094313&path-prefix=en",
  "socialTitle":"my titu",
  "socialDescription":"descripotio"
  }  

},
"suffix": {
 "option":"UNGUESSABLE"
},
}
```